# ListBox ItemContainerStyle does not register white space click

Tags: wpf, listbox

Putting in an `ItemContainerStyle` no longer registers when clicking on white space within the `ListBoxItem`.

Background: I have a `ListBox` where I want to customize the `ItemContainerStyle`. The style works, however, it brings up a new issue, the `ListBox` no longer changes selection when clicking the white space within a `ListBoxItem`.  Using the arrow keys works perfectly and if I click on a control within the `ListBoxItem` then the selection is changed

Here is my `ItemContainerStyle`

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="RegListBoxItem">
<Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50" />
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border Name="_Border"
                        Padding="2"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0" />
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="100" />
                        <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="25" ShadowDepth="8" Direction="270" Color="Black" Opacity=".42" RenderingBias="Performance" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I know it is the `ItemContainerStyle` because if I remove the ItemContainerStyle from the ListBox it works correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Set the Border's Background to Transparent.

Comment: Actually @Clemens this won't work, I had this problem before, what OP needs to do is to use a colour with Alpha channel at 0 this way click will be triggered. Use say `#00FFFFFF`. HTH

Comment: @XAMlMAX [`Colors.Transparent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.transparent(v=vs.110).aspx) (or `Brushes.Transparent` here) is `#00FFFFFF`. As opposed to a Background of `null` (which is the default), you will get input events if you set `Background="Transparent"`.

Comment: You're right @Clemens just read the article. To the OP I have just tested your code and it works for me you can have a look at my code [here](https://github.com/jaworekplay/WPFFrameBindingProblem)

Comment: @Clemens if you put this as an answer I will mark it as the correct one.